# Read file upload - jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple upload box:

```
<input type="file" id="signature" />
```

And use this jQuery:

```
 $('#save').click(function() {
        var element = $('#signature');

        if (element.files && element.files[0]) {
            console.log("Can read image");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failure");
        }
  }
```

It always hits "Failure". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `element` is jQuery's object, not DOM Element, so it does not have property `files`. You can use `var element = $('#signature')[0];`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2oq56ofe/1/).

Comment: Perfect - thanks. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` is jQuery's object, not DOM Element, so it does not have property `files`. You can use:

```
var element = $('#signature')[0];
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2oq56ofe/1/).